# How to make content display below a horizontal div?

Tags: jquery

Okay so the title may sound confusing and this is why I have created an image explaining how I would like this to work; here's that image;

[image]

Here's my code;

HTML:

```
    <div class="link">
    <!--nav-1-->        
    <div id="showmenu1" class="font-white">Click Here</div>
        <div class="menu1" id="font-white" style="display: none;">This is all some random text!</div>
    <!--nav-2-->
    <div id="showmenu2" class="font-white">Click Here</div>
        <div class="menu2" id="font-white" style="display: none;">This is all some random text!</div>
    <!--nav-3-->
    <div id="showmenu3" class="font-white">Click Here</div>
        <div class="menu3" id="font-white" style="display: none;">This is all some random text!</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.link div{
display: inline;
padding: 2px;
letter-spacing: 6px;
text-align: center;
}
```

jQuery (show.js):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showmenu1').click(function() {
            $('.menu1').slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

jQuery (show1.js):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showmenu1').click(function() {
            $('.menu1').slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

jQuery (show2.js):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showmenu1').click(function() {
            $('.menu1').slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

Any help is always appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You've got a lot of issues there.  Why don't you try to mess around with it at http://jsFiddle.net?  I'll give you a hint: You don't want everything to be `display: inline;`.  That's your first issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute [starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector to simplify your code:

```
$("[id^=showmenu]").click(function() {
    $("[class^=menu]").hide();
    $(this).next().slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Then add this style to your hidden div that you want to show on click:

```
.menu1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/937W5/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Add submenus to another div element. Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qHD8R

```
<div class="link">
    <!--nav-1-->        
    <div id="showmenu1" class="font-white">Click Here</div>

    <!--nav-2-->
    <div id="showmenu2" class="font-white">Click Here</div>

    <!--nav-3-->
    <div id="showmenu3" class="font-white">Click Here</div>
</div>
<div class="sub">

    <div class="menu1" id="font-white" style="display: none;">This is all some random text!</div>

    <div class="menu2" id="font-white" style="display: none;">This is all some random text!</div>

    <div class="menu3" id="font-white" style="display: none;">This is all some random text!</div>

</div>
```

And some css.

```
.link div, .sub div {
display: inline-block;
padding: 2px;
text-align: center;
width: 150px;
}

.font-white {
    width: 150px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 3px solid green;
}

.menu1, .menu2, .menu3 {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 3px solid green;
}
```